# IOS - SWIFT - CollectionView -> ImageView load URL image

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, collectionview

I have a CollectionView with images that should loads from net.

the URLs is in array of strings, and in the collectionView cell is imageView.

and i found this code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ViewCell

    var url = NSURL(string: "\(array[indexPath.row])")

    var err: NSError?
    var imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)!
    var bgImage = UIImage(data:imageData)

    cell.imgView.image = bgImage

   // cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])
    cell.load.hidden = false
    cell.load.startAnimating()
    cell.load.hidesWhenStopped = true
    if cell.imgView.image == nil {
        cell.load.startAnimating()
    }else{
        cell.load.stopAnimating()
    }
    return cell
}
```

the problem appearse just at the start.
app is loaded and i see some coments from println in my MainVC (which is with collectionView) but on ipad it just frezen launch screen.

i tried to pu entry point to another view and it works fine until i segue to MainVC, everything just frize and doesnt resond on any touches.

what can be wrong with that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are loading the image on main thread on below code line.

```
var imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)!
```

Download the image asynchronously and update the respective cell once the image is downloaded.

Example:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-apps-using-swift-part-5-async-image-loading-and-caching/

Comment: Hello, i just copied the example from developer.apple and i got a problem witth it, there is a [code image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-5zXuxEf8WnQndqYUo5TEtCaVk/view?usp=sharing) and it seem like i done something wrong, i getting nil values. by the way the app is launches and work properly but there is lonely load indicatiors)